# Why is Haskell monadic bind left-associative?

Tags: haskell, monads

The `>>=` and `>>` operators are both `infixl 1`. Why the left-associativity?

In particular, I observe the equivalences:

```
(do a; b; c ) == (a >> (b >> c))   -- Do desugaring
(a >> b >> c) == ((a >> b) >> c)   -- Fixity definition
```

So `do` is desugared differently to how the fixity definition naturally works, which is surprising.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be left-associative? You wouldn't want `monad >>= action1 >>= action2` being parsed as `monad >>= (action1 >>= action2)`, would you?

Comment: Also, the fixity of `>>` doesn't theoretically matter, since it is associative by the monad laws.

Comment: @AJFarmar worth noting that the usual set of actions you'd want to bind is m a, a->m b, b->m c so the right-associated bind wouldn't typecheck

Comment: @W.Schlieper That's what I'm pointing out.

Comment: The fixity of `<>` doesn't theoretically matter because of Monoid laws, apart from of course it would make list concatenation _O(n^2)_. You've given a good reason for `>>=`, so that's half the answer, but why `>>`?

Comment: For `>>` it would often be better to associate the other way, but maybe this was chosen for consistency with `>>=`.

Comment: It would feel weird if `>>=` and `>>` did not associate the same way.

Comment: @NeilMitchell `>>` can be thought of as a monoid operation ('monads are monoids in the category of endofunctors'), and by corollary is associative.

Comment: @AJFarmar It is worth it to mention that the monoids in "monads are monoids [...]" lie in "the category of endofunctors", and not in **Hask** -- the relevant monoid multiplication is `join :: M (M a) -> M a`. From that, it does follow that, for a `Monad` `M`, `M ()` is a (plain old, **Hask**) monoid, with `return ()` as unit and `(>>)` as multiplication.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`>>=` must surely be left-associative.

```
Prelude> ["bla","bli di","blub"] >>= words >>= reverse
"albilbidbulb"
Prelude> ["bla","bli di","blub"] >>= (words >>= reverse)

<interactive>:3:30: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[[b0]]’
                  with actual type ‘String -> [String]’
    • Probable cause: ‘words’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘words’
      In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘(words >>= reverse)’
      In the expression:
        ["bla", "bli di", "blub"] >>= (words >>= reverse)
```

And `>>` pretty much follows `>>=`; if it had another fixity it would not only  *feel weird* as Lennart said, it would also prevent you from using both operators in a chain:

```
Prelude> ["bla","bli di","blub"] >>= words >> "Ha"
"HaHaHaHa"
Prelude> infixr 1 ⬿≫; (⬿≫) = (>>)
Prelude> ["bla","bli di","blub"] >>= words ⬿≫ "Ha"

<interactive>:6:1: error:
    Precedence parsing error
        cannot mix ‘>>=’ [infixl 1] and ‘⬿≫’ [infixr 1] in the same infix expression
```

Comment: This is the key observation - you couldn't chain both operators if it wasn't infixl.

Answer (score 9):

`>>=` is left-associative because it's convenient. We want `m >>= f1 >>= f2` to be parsed as `(m >>= f1) >>= f2`, not as `m >>= (f1 >>= f2)`, which would likely not type check, as pointed out in the comments.

The associativity of `>>` however, is simply a mirror of `>>=`. This is likely for the sake of consistency, since we can prove that `>>` is associative via the third monad law: `(m >>= f) >>= g ≡ m >>= ( \x -> f x >>= g )`. That is to say, its associativity doesn't theoretically matter. Here is the proof:

```
-- Definition:
a >> b ≡ a >>= (\_ -> b)

-- Proof: (a >> b) >> c ≡ a >> (b >> c)
  (a >> b) >> c
≡ (a >>= (\_ -> b)) >> c                  -- [Definition]
≡ (a >>= (\_ -> b)) >>= (\_ -> c)         -- [Definition]
≡ a >>= (\x -> (\_ -> b) x >>= (\_ -> c)) -- [Monad law]
≡ a >>= (\_ -> b >>= (\_ -> c))           -- [Beta-reduction]
≡ a >>= (\_ -> b >> c)                    -- [Definition]
≡ a >> (b >> c)                           -- [Definition]
∎
```

`do`-notation de-sugars differently because it has a different goal. Essentially, since do-notation is essentially writing out a lambda, right-association is needed. This is because `m >>= (\v -> (...))` is written as `do {v <- m; (...)}`. As earlier, the de-sugaring of `>>` here seems to follow `>>=` for the sake of consistency.